# Typeof data in GridView/ Listview bound, template and auto-generated fields

Tags: asp.net, gridview, listview, export-to-excel, jet

**Background**: I'm populating lots of asp.net c# GridViews and ListViews from a database and subsequently users may export them to Excel. I want export as native Excel (not html). I can't use office automation, and I'm using JET which works fine. I have no control over users' machines.

---

**Question**: When doing the export, you have to tell Jet what type each field is, in my case "text" (varchar) or "numeric" (double). The difference is that if you export a numeric column, the users can sum the data in Excel, where as strings are exported with a leading apostrophe and so are not much use in arithmetic.

Currently I parse the first data row of the Grid/ListView, check if each value is numeric or text, and assign a type to the column accordingly. That works, except for when I have something in the first column which looks numeric but in fact is a text string. I don't want to parse every row in order to be sure I have the correct data type as some of these exports are quite large.

When I load the Grid/ListView from the database, the database certainly knows what type each field is. So my question is... how do I extract the type of the database item behind a a Grid/ListView item? I could explicitly code it as an attribute on the item, but that's duplicating information I already have, if only I can get to it.

I know that where I have a DataTable then I can get the underlying type from that, but mostly I don't have tables handy, just the Grid/ListView.

--
(edit)
Note that Jet will throw if you try to insert an empty string into a nullable numeric column. The way to do this is to omit that column name from the insert statement, or output a zero.

Answer (score 0):

I think what your trying to do is figure out the underlying `DataSource` of the `GridView` or `ListView` after it has been bound?

If so that is no possible since the controls don't really keep track of the `DataSource` once the has been bound.  They are mainly used to fill it's columns, templates, etc and then just those items are maintained.

The only recommendation I can offer is to store the `DataSource` in another location so that you can access it later and then use it to discover the underlying datatypes used for each column.  You could store it in the `Session` or `ViewState` if you want but this will add overhead.  The other option would be to figure out the datatypes before binding and then storing them in a hidden field with some type of format you can use later to replicate what was being done.

Eg (bad example but gives you an idea) Store in a hidden field the following data:

```
yourHiddenField.Text = "0,1|1,1|2,0|3,1|etc...";
// format "columnindex,fieldtype(0=double,1=string)" with a pipe delimiter.
```

Not pretty but illustrates the basic idea I am thinking of.

Comment: Mmm... I'm trying to avoid coding the data type anywhere explicitly, as the database knows what it is, and I don't want to duplicate that knowledge. Perhaps there's no way to avoid coding it.

Comment: @philw you wouldn't be doing it explicitly, you would just be capturing that information and storing in a format that would make it accessible.  At the point you need it, it is gone, so you need a way to get the data there.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the answer is "you can't". My data sources return only strings, so you can't usefully parse any auto-created DataTable for column types.

---

**What I did was**...

Most column types I can "sniff" from looking at the 1st row of the grid/list. This fails only if 1st column data is null (which tells you nothing), or if the 1st column implies numeric but the column data is for example alpha-numeric.

So for those columns where I know there's a problem, or where testing shows there to be so, I annotate those specific Grid or ListView items with a custom attribute which forces the items to be exported as text or numeric. I default to text, so in practice I mostly just have to annotate those entries I specifically want to render as numeric. Exceptions are some ID numbers which start with leading zeros, which I want to render that way hence go explicitly as text.

Where I have a DataTable (eg for charts), and I can't do the sniffing trick (see above), or the annotation trick (ditto), then I pass a map of the column types to my export code.

In summary, in some cases I am forced to repeat the column type definition either in the Grid/ListView template fields, or in the field-map. Can't win them all. It does work.